# Use joblib and @jit (numba library)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, joblib

Does using joblib Parallel, delayed etc architecture and @jit decorators make one or the other redundant in the sence that code wont run?

Comment: for simple cases I successfully used @njit and joblib together.